# Sharepoint Collaboration Portal initial size

Tags: sharepoint, collaboration, portal, teamsite

Around how much space does a Sharepoint Collaboration Portal use up by default (when newly created)?

Just asking because I had one created but I'm thinking of using a Team Site site template--if the client won't be utilizing the default "features" of a Collaboration Portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told that it takes little space only (so I shouldn't worry)